# form elements not clickable

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I am developing a system I have been asked to do but the form elements are not clickable to enter any info in the fields, I have tried moving the form tag to above the very first div in the code below in case it was the issue but did not work unfortunately. I am not sure what else to try, can someone have a look at the code below please

Update: I have got the form elements working by adding `zindex: 9999;` to `.form-group` class in the CSS but now the datetimepicker is appearing behind the select dropdown menu. I have uploaded a screenshot of the issue to the link below

Here is a screenshot of my issue:

[image]

My code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-12" id="detail">

  <form name="addData" id="addData" action="" method="post">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <input type="hidden" name="eventID" id="eventID" class="form-control">
        <label for="StartDate">Start Date: </label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" required name="StartDate" id="StartDate" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="StartTime" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">Start Time: </label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
          <input name="StartTime" id="StartTime" type='text' required class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
              format: 'LT'
            });
          });
        </script>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="StartDate">End Date: </label>
        <input type="date" required class="form-control" name="EndDate" id="EndDate" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="EndTime" style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">End Time: </label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker4'>
          <input name="EndTime" id="EndTime" required type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
              format: 'LT'
            });
          });
        </script>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="riders_name">Riders Name: </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="height: 34px;" required name="riders_name" id="riders_name"></select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="horses_name">Horses Name : </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="height: 34px;" required name="horses_name" id="horses_name">
          <option value="">--Empty--</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="instructor_name">Instructor Name : </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="height: 34px;" required name="instructor_name" id="instructor_name">
          <option value="">--Empty--</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="groom_name">Groom Name : </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="height: 34px;" required name="groom_name" id="groom_name">
          <option value="">--Empty--</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-lg-9">
        <label for="comments">Comments : </label>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="Repeat">Repeat : </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="height: 34px;" required name="Repeat" id="Repeat">
          <option value="0">none</option>
          <option value="1">Daily</option>
          <option value="2">Weekly</option>
          <option value="3">Monthly</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
        &nbsp;
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
        &nbsp;
      </div>

    </div>

  </form>

</div>

<script>
  $.getJSON("fullcalendar/getriders.php", function(data) {
    var select = $('#riders_name'); //combo/select/dropdown list
    if (select.prop) {
      var options = select.prop('options');
    } else {
      var options = select.attr('options');
    }
    $('option', select).remove();

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(value['name'], value['id']);
    });
  });

  $.getJSON("fullcalendar/getinstructors.php", function(data) {
    var select = $('#instructor_name'); //combo/select/dropdown list
    if (select.prop) {
      var options = select.prop('options');
    } else {
      var options = select.attr('options');
    }
    $('option', select).remove();
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(value['name'], value['id']);
    });
  });


  $.getJSON("fullcalendar/getgrooms.php", function(data) {
    var select = $('#groom_name'); //combo/select/dropdown list
    if (select.prop) {
      var options = select.prop('options');
    } else {
      var options = select.attr('options');
    }
    $('option', select).remove();
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(value['name'], value['id']);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i am not able to reproduce it, can you create a snippet of the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/xy9L486p/

Comment: I tried to create a jsfiddle but the fields work there but are not a inline form, I added the other code from the php file such as the javascript and fullcalendar fields but weird thing is it's works still but don't work on the php page

I don't get it, I'll keep looking into the issue

Comment: I have managed to get the form elements clickable now, I added z-index: 9999; to form-group class in the css but now the datetimepicker widget is appearing behind the select dropdown menu. I have tried adding z-index: 9999; to .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget but does not work, I have uploaded a screenshot to the original post above

Comment: Just managed to solve the issue, I added z-index: 999; to the div class for the select menus and looks all ok now

The code used is below

<div class="form-group col-lg-3" style="z-index: 999;">
                <label for="horses_name">Horses Name : </label>
                <select class="form-control" style="height: 34px;" required name="horses_name" id="horses_name">
        <option value="">--Empty--</option>
    </select>
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

I see several empty `<select></select>` tags in your form. I suspect you are intending text fields there? If so you need to replace `<select></select>` with `<input type="text" />`.

Example, this:

```
<label for="riders_name">Riders Name: </label>
<select class="form-control" style="height: 34px;" required name="riders_name" id="riders_name"></select>
```

...should be:

```
<label for="riders_name">Riders Name: </label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" style="height: 34px;" required name="riders_name" id="riders_name" />
```

Comment: The select tags are pulling data in from a database table so need to be select tags rather than input text fields

Answer (score 0):

Select drop down always higher z-index set by default by browsers. You have two row one underneath other. You should in top row set higher z-index value with position: relative; then I hope it will work as expected.

Add CSS code with following way:

```
.higher-z-index {
    postion: relative; // This line help z-index work relatively 
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Your markup will be something like that:

```
<div class="row higher-z-index">
    .....
    ....
</div>
<div class="row">
    .....
    ....
</div>
```

**Why this approach:**

You should keep it mind this is dose not matter how much z-index value applied in `.form-group` selector it will work for only sibling elements. But in your case it is going behind of next row elements because modern browsers set by default higher z-index in each next sibling elements until we set explicitly. So underneath row getting higher z-index than top row. So it is dose not matter how many higher z-index value are applied inside of top row container, all will go behind of next row container.